# Highcharts - How do I change the filter styling?

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

In highcharts (bubble) I have a filter.  The problem is that when applied, it renders the filtered data in a really ugly manner.

This is an example of the code when I inspect the element:

```
<circle fill-opacity="0.5" fill="rgb(255,255,255)" stroke-width="2" stroke="#000000" r="230.5" cy="491.60872727272726" cx="579"></circle>
```

I would like to simply have bubbles that get removed to disappear completely and my remaining bubbles to remain as they were (transparent fill and 1px #000 solid border)

Any hints on how to achieve this?

Thanks
Jacques
EDIT - screen captures added:

[image: Normal]
[image: Filtered]

Comment: Could you create jsFiddle demo with that 'really ugly manner'?

Comment: Pawel
I can send you a screenshot, as the data and filter html is quite big?
I will edit the answer with the screenshot.

Comment: JSfiddle? bubble chart on their site has graph, this has custom styling so we need those information

Comment: We really can't tell you how to fix your filter if we can't see what you're doing to filter the data...

Comment: On another note, although you'll get points for making it pretty, this is a very ineffective way to show the data. Judging or comparing the values involved is nearly impossible in this format, and a bar chart would show the data in a much more effective way.  FWIW

Comment: @jlbriggs I know, not really pretty but this is what the client wants.  I will try and create a JSFIDDLE.  Is there a way to print out my data so that I can use it directly in the fiddle?

Comment: I don't know how your filtering is working, but after that you should simply call `series.data[index].hide()` to hide specific bubble.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I alter SVG styles?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25793161/how-do-i-alter-svg-styles)

Comment: @RobertLongson - I would rather say that above topic is the duplicated one..

Comment: You can only mark questions as duplicates if they have answers so it's only possible this way round.